# Actionscript 2: Hittest on multiple MCs

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I am running a hittest on an array of thousands of MCs a little a part, due to the nature of this sometimes two can be hit at once.

How would I narrow it down so that the one which is hit the most is the one returned value?

Answer (score 1):

Have a specific variable increment each time a specific movieclip is hit.
Place all of these variables in an array.

sortOn the array for DESCENDING order.

select the first element in the array (myArray[0]), as that will have the highest value